# Creating a model procedurally through coding?

Tags: models, procedural-generation, procedural

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a basic character skeleton from code](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21489/creating-a-basic-character-skeleton-from-code)

I'd like to have a procedural system that uses a string of data to create a 3d creature. The way I've thought to do this is to use the code to generate a simple creature frame, and later add something to add additional detail.The goal is to create creatures of different forms and frame. The creation will be mirrored down the spine so both sides are the same.

I assume it will work best to generate it like bones so the code would have information used to show what type of bone it was(hierarchy), the bone length, and how the bone was positioned and use this to make the model. (At least in planning, I don't know how to implement it)

I'd like it to be highly adaptable but I'd like to specify a max of 4 legs and 4 arms (8 limb max only 4 on ground for walking). Being able to create a basic structure for humanoids, quadrupeds, and mixes (like a centaur or biped with no arms) is the goal.

I've looked into turtle graphics, l-systems, metaballs, and FReps. But I still don't know what to use. How can I use a set of data to generate the simple 3d frame?